# Retrieve count data from Firebase like MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When trying to pull data from a MySQL database, I can do something like:

`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id WHERE vehicle = car`

That should get me all the users that drives a car and not show users that drives a motorcycle for instance.

Is there something like this for Firebase? I can only retrieve specific data from one user?

My firebase database is like this: user -> user info (name, age, vehicle etc..)

I want to query every user that drives a car and display them in a row. How do I do that?

---

I have tried the following, but I didn't succeed with what I tried to do, since after `users` the users id is the next child. Is there a way to query past that?

```js
var recents = firebase.database().child('users').orderByChild('department').equalTo(department);
            recents.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
            var countOfUserInDepartment = snapshot.count;
            
                document.querySelector("#cphCount").innerHTML = countOfUserInDepartment;
            
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no count queries (nor other aggregation queries) in the Firebase Database. Your options are:

1. Retrieve all data matching your query and count client-side
2. Keep a separate count-node that you update whenever you add/remove items.

For #2 you may find it convenient to use Cloud Functions, for which there an an [example of keeping such a counter](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count).

Also see:

- [Firebase count group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331071/firebase-count-group-by/26346400#26346400)
- [Database-style Queries with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587775/database-style-queries-with-firebase/11588115#11588115)
- [In Firebase, is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load/15149311#15149311)
- [How to get size of an element/list in Firebase without get it all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443421/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-list-in-firebase-without-get-it-all/38444523#38444523)

Comment: You use the standard Firebase methods for [reading a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists) or [querying a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: I have edited my question. How can I query past a child that I "don't know what is"?

Comment: I reopened the question, but have no idea why you mention **count** in your title. You might want to update that, so that hopefully somebody will be able to help better..